# Windows Server 2012 R2 FTP folders do not refresh data automatically

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have set up a new IIS FTP Service in our local subnet and added 40 user accounts. Everything works successfully except one thing: whatever is written by the server inside a user's folder, does not appear on his mapped Windows 7 drive automatically, neither by refreshing it.

Only hack that works is creating a new file with New -> Text Document and then everything appears. It seems that the new file creation somehow "triggers" the folder to fetch data. What could be the fault ?

Comment: Is this for internal use only? If so, why don't you just create a shared folder (or folders)?

Comment: because another server is writing a text file in each of the users folders via FTP and the users must view it by using a shared network folder.